# Get all derived types of an abstract class within all the assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

I have a library that has an abstract class inside - suppose `MyAbstractClass`. This library is being used by some other projects (one app) within one solution.

I want to get all these classes. I created sample `Program` project and `Program.Library` that contains `MyAbstractClass`.

I have created two test classes derived from `MyAbstractClass`. One in the first project (`Test1Class`) and one in the second one (`Test2Class`).

I tried this code to find what I want:

```
var list = Assembly.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                                .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof (MyAbstractClass)));
```

It worked but found only `Test1Class` (because - I guess - it's placed in the same assembly as the executed code presented above?). I don't know how to find all the derived classes within all the assemblies in my whole app.

I have also tried:

```
var list = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyAbstractClass)).GetTypes()
                                .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof (MyAbstractClass)));
```

But this one gives me an empty collection...

Comment: Is the assembly containing "TestClass2" already loaded when you call your `Assembly.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`?

Comment: I'll add an answer, please mark it as accepted if you think it was helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be sure that all assemblies you want to look in are already loaded when you call `Assembly.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`;
An Assembly get loaded when the runtime need it (i.e. when your program reach a point in your code that "use" that assembly, or if you specifically call a `Assembly.Load` or `Assembly.LoadFile` or whatever method you can use to explicitly load it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() only lists the Assemblies currently loaded in your Application Domain.
If you want to get the types in all assemblies in your application, then you need to ensure (somehow) that all assemblies are loaded.

One way of loading the assemblies manually is to use the following line of code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@filename)
```

You'd need to do the above for each file, and then you can use the method CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().